# Выполнить код одновременно

Tags: c#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Opacity = 0;
        FadeIn();

    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Closing -= Window_Closing;
        e.Cancel = true;

        DoubleAnimation fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350));
        fadeOut.Completed += (s, _) => Close();
        BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
    }

    private void FadeIn()
    {
        DoubleAnimation fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        DoubleAnimation scaleWidth = new DoubleAnimation(Width * 1.1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350));
        DoubleAnimation scaleHeight = new DoubleAnimation(Height * 1.1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350));

        BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeIn);
        BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, scaleWidth);
        BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, scaleHeight);
    }
}
```

Анимация идет друг за другом, а как ее выполнить одновременно? Пробовал потоки, но нельзя обращаться к GUI

Comment: У вас WinForms? Из потоков можно обращаться к ГУИ, только немного сложнее. Но простое применение потоков никак не гарантирует одновременность выполнения.

Comment: Нет, у меня WPF

Comment: Покажите полный код

Comment: Обновил код выше

Comment: Хм, а с чего вы взяли, что анимация идет друг за другом? Нет смысла что-либо анимировать *до* того, как произойдет событие `Loaded`

Comment: Визуально наблюдаю. Написал на код на событие `Loaded` - тот же эффект

Comment: Я переписал вот так: https://pastebin.com/Lc0g3Pxc здесь видно, что анимация идет одновременно, подозреваю, что всё-таки окна рисуются системой и система не позволяет так быстро менять свойства окна, поэтому возникают задержки и на коротких интервалах получается последовательная анимация. Анимация элементов внутри окна таких проблем не имеет, потому что она выполняется чисто средствами WPF. Вероятно, вам придется добиваться нужного эффекта "по-старинке" — с помощью таймеров. Пробуйте...

Comment: И в правду. Но, fadeIn и scaleWidth выполняются одновременно, а вот scaleHeight после них. Хех, придется все таки юзать таймер. Но спасибо и на этом